# How to get full width screenshot of current tab using getThumbnail() Tab API of Firefox addons sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox extension using its addons SDK in which I need to capture a thumbnail of the current tab. For that, I am using `getThumbnail()` [Tab API of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#getThumbnail%28%29) addons sdk.
Its working quiet well but not capturing the full width image of the loaded page. Seems it capturing about 80% of the full width of the tab/window/page.

I am using following workaround requiring,

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
```

Then using,

```
var imageDataUri = tabs.activeTab.getThumbnail();
```

Is there any way to get the screenshot of the current tab in full width by this method?

Comment: Here is the [scenario](http://i.imgur.com/LKf7WMW.png) where the blue square should be captured inside the red square but its not capturing the full width.

Comment: Somebody help this guy out. I dont know sdk otherwise i would.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the code generating the thumbnail [here](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/content/thumbnail.js).

there are some magic numbers there that might be causing this problem for you e.g.

```
let snippetWidth = window.innerWidth * .6;
```

copy this code into your extension and tweak it to get the desired result.

to get the `window` argument for this function, you can use the low-level tabs from [tabs/utils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/tabs_utils) and get a tab's window with `getBrowserForTab(low_level_tab).contentWindow`